# yii2 customize a bootbox modal instead of alert on data-confirm

Tags: javascript, yii2, bootbox

For example here I want to change alert for a bootbox.alert(...

```
'delete' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', $url, [
                        'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Delete'),
                        'class'=>'btn btn-primary',
                        'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'),
                        'data-method' => 'post',
                        'data-pjax' => '0',
                    ]);
                },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a HTML class to the element, drop the "data-confirm" param and use a "click" event.
That way you can execute whatever you want when the link is clicked.

```
'delete' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', $url, [
                    'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Delete'),
                    'class'=>'btn btn-primary delete-button',
                    'data-id' => $model->id, // For using when the button is clicked
                ]);
            },
```

And inside your javascript file:

```
$(".delete-button").on("click",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var modelId = $(this).data('id');
   // Run bootbox.alert() here!!
   // Based on the bootbox result, you can decide to fire the initial event again:
   // $(this).unbind('submit').submit()
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Nice!!, jus may I will need make a $.ajax... type:post, because for delete is a post request, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just assign a class name or id : "id"=>"btn-id"
Then override click event :

```
$("#btn-id").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   //Somethings and return here
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Link Overriding yii.js confirm --> bootbox.confirm.

[Yii 2.0: Escape from Default's Yii2 Delete Confirm Box :](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/3511)